# LaTex inline math $...$ problem in WinEdt

Tags: winedt, inline

In WinEdt10, the inline math is italic, and the subscript "_" is no longer visible. I need to turn off the italic format of the inline mode $...$. Can anyone help with the issue?
[image]

Comment: Actually, `$$...$$` is deprecated syntax in LaTeX, regardless which editor you're using

Comment: Which version of WinEdt do you employ? There’s a WinEdt help forum. Have you contacted it?

Comment: Have you tried to change font? I remember I had a similar problem eons ago,  although it was on Linux.

Comment: with winedt 10.3 i can't reproduce your problem. the  subscript "_"  is clear visible.

Comment: I use WinEdt10.3. In the older version, the text inside $...$ does not set italic. However, in WinEdt 10.3, the text inside $...$ are set italic, so the subscript is not visible. If anyone knows how to turn off the italic font for the $...$ environment, it should fix the problem.

Comment: I agree with Zarko, there is no problem seeing the underscore with WinEdt v10.3. Maybe this is a "scaling" problem, i.e. a combination of font size and screen resolution? Could you state both? Besides that I agree with Mico that this question might be better suited for the WinEdt mailing list ...

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your default language, font selection and/ or display magnification.

The best solution is to leave highlighting as is (italics) AND increase the "Extra Line Spacing (Below)" until the underline is visible. This can be done in the Font Tab of the Preferences Dialog (WinEdt Options Menu). The default value is 1 pixel but in some cases 2, 3, or even 4 pixels might be required in order to prevent the italics underline to be clipped.

If desired, it is also possible to disable the italic attribute. This is done in the Options Interface -> Highlighting: Colors, Keywords...

Double click on Switches and in Switches.ini search for line:

SWITCH="$?$"

Change the last line in this item from:

```
ITALIC=1
```

to

```
ITALIC=0
```

and reload the script (the first button in the toolbar of the options interface).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.
In my case the "Extra spacing below" was 0. Making it 1 fixed the problem.
Go Options-Preferences-font and check it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!